# Unable to deduce an upper bound for an complex integral to get the order of growth

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am getting stuck on some detail part of a practice problem.

I am trying to deduce an upper bound for $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|^\alpha} e^{2\pi izt}dt|$ to get the order of growth in the form $Ae^{B|x|^\beta}$. This is the exercise 5.5 in Stein complex analysis. [I have looked through all other posts related to this question, but I don't the responses under those posts helped me understand how it works. ]

According to the hint, I have successfully deduced $-\frac{|t|^\alpha}{2}+2\pi |z||t| \leq c|z|^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha -1}}$.

Therefore, I claimed $|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|^\alpha} e^{2\pi izt}dt|\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|^\alpha/2} e^{-|t|^\alpha / 2 + 2\pi i|z||t|}dt$.

I want to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|^\alpha/2} e^{-|t|^\alpha / 2 + 2\pi |z||t|}dt \leq ke^{c|z|^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}$, but I am not sure how I should take off the integral part.

I see $e^{-|t|^\alpha / 2 + 2\pi |z||t|}\leq e^{c|z|^\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}$, but then how should I handle the other half integrand $e^{-|t|^\alpha/2} $?

1. I don't think I can divide $e^{2\pi |k| |t|}$ because I do want to have $|t|$ on one side.
2. I have taken the absolute value, so I can't see $e^{2\pi |k| |t|}$ as a change of orientation either.

Also, I thought in general $\int f(x)\leq \int g(x)$ when $f(x)\leq g(x)$, but here I am trying to get something like $\int f(x) \leq g(x)$. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: For $|t| \gg |z|$, $\exp(-|t|^\alpha/2 + 2\pi|z||t|) \leq 1$, so you can imagine the only contribution to the integral is $\exp(-|t|^\alpha/2)$, which will just be some finite constant even if integrated over all reals. For $|t|$ small compared to $|z|$, your extra term $\exp(-|t|^\alpha/2) \leq 1$ anyway, so integrating over that interval just multiplies by a constant. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Hi Joshua. What a good strategy! I didn't think of using the diminishing property to get a constant. I think I got it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I could not reply at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3884375/42969 anymore because the question is already deleted. The related question were found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5CVert%20f%27%20%5CVert%20%5Cleq%202%5Csqrt%7B%5CVert%20f%20%5CVert%20%5CVert%20f%27%27%20%5CVert%20%7D%24). Another math search engine is [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com). See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048 for more information.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Sorry for deletion. I am green to this website so I didn't know how this forum works. I didn't know these two sites at all, and they both seem very helpful!